# How can I get JComboboxItem when mouseEnter?

Tags: java, swing, mouse, jcombobox

I have JCombobox "Location", its item is countries name. I want then mouse enter each item, it will show another JcomboBox with city of each Country. How can I do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making an unusable GUI.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson... Yeah, JCombobox can't help this problem. I think I should make class like JMenu to add in JTable Cell. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds more like what you want is an `ActionListener` attached to the `JComboBox` which you can then use to determine when the user changes the selected item.  Remember, the user change use the keyboard to

See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

To make your life easier, I would create a `Country` class which contains a `List` of `City` objects.  This way, when the `Country` is selected, you can easily pull the `List` of `City` objects associated with out and populate the second list

Comment: The City object is not visible when user not move mouse enter. The problem is I want when mouseEnter each item in JcomboBox not selected Item, the City JCombobox would appeared with another item. How can i get combobox Item when mouse over it?

Comment: As a user, I will hate, but take a look at the `ItemListener` instead

Comment: Think of the sight challenged users who don't use a mouse!  Definitely go with the `ActionListener` rather than make yet another 'unusable GUI'..

Comment: @Andrew Thompson... So I think I should make a Component like JMenu for user. how can I add JMenu or class extends Menu to Jtable Cell

Comment: @gianglaodai Don't, that's not how they are suppose to be used.  You could associate a `JPopupMenu` with the `JTable` and customise it based on the row/column that was clicked to activate it...

Comment: @MadProgramer...Thanks, that helpful.